# Character-wise string diff in PHP

Tags: php, string, diff

In short I am looking for something like google-diff-match-patch in PHP.

I have had a look at some similar questions at SO, and also at the algorithm provided [here](http://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/blob/5bfe1d2a8f967c7901ace50f04ac2d9308ed3169/simplediff.php), but all of them fail:

```
diff("draßen", "da draußen")
```

should *not* give

```
<del>draßen</del> <ins>da draußen</ins>
```

(which is kind of stupid for my purpose, because I want to compare file names), but [(try here)](http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html)

```
<ins>da </ins>dra<ins>u</ins>ßen
```

Is there a code snippet in PHP that does this? Unfortunately, I cannot use (i.e. install) external packages.

Comment: Not sure this is what you want / need, but give this PHP function a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php. There's also the levenshtein algorithm there, at "See also".

Comment: You could define a threshhold percentage for when the check 'in-word' diffs with `similar_text()`. Haven't got the time to work out an example a.t.m. though.

Comment: In the [API Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API) on the Google Code page you link to there is mention of a partial PHP implementation - although this is not part of the repository as yet.

Comment: @Francisc: No, it's not -- but in fact I'm using right this function to select filenames similar to the one given. Now I want to highlight the differences...

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff supports character-wise diff and can render the differences in HTML

Answer (score 2):

The PEAR Package [Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/) provides Inline-Diffs.

Comment: I know. But I cannot install pear packages afaik.

Comment: You can download the Text_Diff Package as tgz. So you could extract the functions/algorithms you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

There is a php version of google-diff-match-patch available here: https://github.com/nuxodin/diff_match_patch-php

Answer (score 2):

There is a [port](https://github.com/yetanotherape/diff-match-patch) of fresh version [google-diff-match-patch library](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/). 
It is much faster than previous and have no problems wth utf8.